# Can't get ReferenceManyField to display data

Tags: react-admin

Have spent several hours trying to get ReferenceManyField to display some data in a nested DataGrid.

```
<Show {...this.props}> 
  <SimpleShowLayout>
    <TextField source="id" />
    <TextField source="name" />
    {/* THE FOLLOWING COMPONENT DOES NOT DISPLAY ANY DATA. WHY NOT??? */}
    <ReferenceManyField label="Stores" reference="stores" target="companies_id">
      <Datagrid rowClick="show">
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="storeName" />
      </Datagrid>
    </ReferenceManyField>
  </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>
```

I have created a massively stripped down version of my app, which demonstrates the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-referencemanyfield-issue-forked-lde6c

I am certain there has to be a simple explanation for this issue, but as a relative newcomer to React/ReactAdmin/Typescript I just can't see it. What am I doing wrong?

Grateful for any tips & advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared the `stores` resource in your Admin component.

Add a `<Resource name="stores" />` inside `Admin`